How do I associate the contents of a textarea with a dynamically generated name so I can fetch it when posted, preforably initiated with <button>?
I'm an experienced programmer but new to PHP and I'm on my first real project with it.
I'm walking through a tree of files and showing various things - text, images, etc - and when an authorized user is viewing, they get to do special things, for example the script shows them buttons that other people don't see that lets them take certain actions.
This is working pretty well but I'm stuck on how I associate the content of a textarea with the post of a button in a way where I can dynamically create the text area and button but have the code doing the _POST processing - pardon the pun! - receive the contents of the textarea and know what the data's related to, since what it's going to do with it will either be a part of the dynamically generated name, or perhaps a part of the data sent - I don't really care so long as it's not too painful.
ALL the examples I've seen so far presume you have a static situation, and also presume you're using:
<input...

I haven't found any examples of this that do NOT use the input form ... and it's perhaps worth pointing out there that the VAST majority of examples out there are VERY unhelpfully crafted with dramatic overuse of the word "submit" - the least abuse of it I've yet found is in this example:
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Additional Comments:</label><br>
<textarea cols="35" rows="12" name="comments" id="para1">
<php echo $comments; ?>
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit"/></form>

But it still isn't helpful: Is "submit" a keyword or just an arbitrary name?! The novice doesn't know.
In the above I note the use of id, and I've been taking that angle, but here it doesn't appear to be referenced. ... I haven't been able to get the input construct working in my environ - it can't be closely tied in to form creation (or maybe I'm wrong about that?)... But I HAVE got buttons working in every place they're appropriate, so I'm fairly familiar with them by now. What I DON'T understand is how to associate the content of the textarea with the associated button. I DO see how this is done if you're using <input, but I'm not.
I've tried quite a few things but here's where I'm sitting now:
   echo '<textarea name="fileMeta" rows="20" class="textarea"
    id="meta_'.$arrayIndex.'">';
   echo $contents;
   echo "</textarea><br>";
   echo '<button name="saveMeta" value="'.$arrayIndex.
    '" formtarget="_self" formmethod="post" form="thisForm" '.
    'align="left">Save</button>';

(Not part of the question but just By The Way, the class identification doesn't seem to do I damned thing - I tried to use it for css.)
Note how the text area has a dynamically generated id based on the array index. And the button's value contains the same array index. Of course I was planning to join these up - pretty easy... Or so I thought.
After a button is clicked, the idea was the post the code check for "saveMeta", but then... That only gets it the value $arrayIndex.
But it's clear to even this newbie that there's nothing about the button directly tying it to the text area's content. I was hoping that because it's considered form data it'd be passed in a a posting and there's some way to "pull the content out" based on the id. But there doesn't seem to be any way to easily discover - at least for a novice like me - what values were sent back in the _POST array ...
...I'm contemplating dumping the whole _POST array via:
var_dump($_POST);

...and weeding through the debris for my data, and perhaps from that learn if my supposition was correct (that the file text area's in there) and if so how I might find that -ahem- needle in the PHP haystack.
Other than that, I'm stuck.
A creative idea came to me...
...not that I know how to pull it off: Perhaps on the action the button takes it somehow loads the value attribute from the textarea?
WELL, I THOUGHT I HAD IT!
Frustrated, I did indeed do the var_dump, like this:
   if (isset($_POST['saveMeta']))
   {
      var_dump($_POST);
      ...

And what I found was I got TWO elements in the array, the button and the textarea, the one available via "saveMeta", as noted, the other available via "fileMeta", which is the name of the text area!
I WRONGLY figured it was working, I just didn't know how to access the data, ERRANTLY thinking You first look for the button's name, and get the value from that, and THEN you look for the text area's name and you've got your data.
NOPE. For some reason it had the data from the LAST textarea loaded?! This is a weird quirk...

I DO see how this is done if you're using <input it should be the same with a textarea.  They are virtually identical in how they work.

Is "submit" a keyword...no... just an arbitrary name?...yes. And a textarea and an input are quite similar, and work basically the same way in terms of being part of a form, and submitted when a form is submitted

Are you trying to submit one textarea at a time? In that case, put each one in its own <form> (with a button also inside that form), and then when you press the button, only the data inside that form will be submitted. And if you need to send something with it to identify it, either put a value in the button which helps you, or a hidden field inside the form (e.g. with some kind of ID or whatever it is you need in the PHP in order to process the data - it was a little unclear, from your description).

For some reason it had the data from the LAST textarea loaded...yeah because if you have multiple inputs with the same name inside a single <form, then only the last one will be submitted to the server, because field names must be unique. (Exception: if you use array syntax e.g. name="saveMeta[] on each of the affected form fields, then you get a list of values inside $_POST["saveMeta"] - but it doesn't sound like that's what you want.)

P.S. You may find the following resources useful regarding how HTML forms work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/How_to_structure_a_web_form . The PHP side is less relevant - $_POST will contain whatever is sent to the server in the request body, whether the HTTP request came from a HTML form, mobile app, bot or whatever. But it seems like you're struggling with structuring your form (or forms) correctly to send the data you need.

@ADyson Thanks ADyson, I'll reply a bit at a time: YES, one at a time - there are literally hundreds of things on a typical page. You're saying one form each?! ... OK... Yes. already using value for identifying...

@ADyson That saveMeta[] may not be what I'm after now but seems like it's useful. ... THANKS for the links, and yeah, forms aren't well described from my personal point of view.

@ADyson Confident your one-form-each approach will surely work, I recommend you make it an official answer! If I'd been looking and found it, I'd have recognized I should give up on the one-form-for-the-page idea - which is an idea a novice gets when they see buttons APPEAR to be independently active?  Maybe clicking the button "submitted the whole form," but there are a LOT of buttons out there and only the clicked one - and the last text area - were sent...

Maybe clicking the button "submitted the whole form," but there are a LOT of buttons out there and only the clicked one - and the last text area - were sent...yep, only the button which is clicked will be sent, so the server can know which button was clicked. (If you submit a form via JavaScript, for example, no buttons are sent since the form wasn't submitted via a button!) And I've already explained why only the last textarea was sent

Are you trying to submit one textarea at a time? In that case, put each one in its own <form> (with a button also inside that form), and then when you press the button, only the data inside that form will be submitted. And if you need to send something with it to identify it, either put a value in the button which helps you, or a hidden field inside the form (e.g. with some kind of ID or whatever it is you need in the PHP in order to process the data - it was a little unclear, from your description).
e.g.
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="123"/>
  <textarea name="formMeta" rows="20" class="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton"/>
</form>

Repeat this pattern on the page for as many textareas as you need to display at once.

OK, here I think the <input line with value= can get me the array index I need... Trying it now!

Yep, the hidden attribute was the key - easy, clean, and done! ;-) Thanks!
